# groupby count same values in two columns in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following Pandas dataframe:

```
name1   name2
A       B
A       A
A       C
A       A
B       B
B       A
```

I want to add a column named new which counts `name1` **OR** `name2` keeping the merged columns (distinct values in both `name1` and `name2`). Hence, the expected output is the following dataframe:

```
name   new
   A     7
   B     4
   C     1
```

I've tried

`df.groupby(["name1"]).count().groupby(["name2"]).count()`, among many other things... but although that last one seems to give me the correct results, I cant get the joined datasets.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to groupby count across multiple columns in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37911043/how-to-groupby-count-across-multiple-columns-in-pandas)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) with `df.stack()`:

```
df[['name1','name2']].stack().value_counts()
#df.stack().value_counts() for all cols
```

---

```
A    7
B    4
C    1
```

Specifically:

```
(df[['name1','name2']].stack().value_counts().
      to_frame('new').rename_axis('name').reset_index())

  name  new
0    A    7
1    B    4
2    C    1
```

Answer (score 4):

Let us try `melt`

```
df.melt().value.value_counts()
Out[17]: 
A    7
B    4
C    1
Name: value, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks! This is correct, but it works for *any* columns. In other words, it would count items in a third `name3` column as well. Which is great! I'll save it for further user.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively,

```
df.name1.value_counts().add(df.name2.value_counts(), fill_value=0).astype(int)
```

gives you

```
A    7
B    4
C    1
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 3):

Using [`Series.append`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.append.html) with [`Series.value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
df['name1'].append(df['name2']).value_counts()

A    7
B    4
C    1
dtype: int64
```

`value_counts` converts the aggregated column to index. To get your desired output, use `rename_axis` with `reset_index`:

```
df['name1'].append(df['name2']).value_counts().rename_axis('name').reset_index(name='new')

  name  new
0    A    7
1    B    4
2    C    1
```

Answer (score 2):

python `Counter` is another solution

```
from collections import Counter

s = pd.Series(Counter(df.to_numpy().flatten()))

In [1325]: s
Out[1325]:
A    7
B    4
C    1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: @ignoring_gravity: hehe... it's the beauty of python and pandas :)